# derived column Expression with calucation

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an derived column expression in the package need to have an column as below
The below code is working, I need the case 1 to be divided by 100 which is giving error

Table Column Info

```
  [Sales] [numeric](19, 2) NULL
```

Expression used in the SSIS Expression

```
  [Currency_SID]==369 ?   [Sales] : [Sales]
```

When i use this , i am getting red.. which is the error

```
 [Currency_SID]==369 ?   [Sales]/ 100  : [Sales]
```

kindly help me with syntax

Comment: whould help if you say what error is

Comment: Try this:  [Currency_SID]==369 ?   [Sales]/ 100.00  : [Sales]

Comment: just keep your mouse over the red... it will display you what is the error. and mention here what error you are getting

Comment: Maybe you have `NULL` inside `Sales` ?